# Wordpress image preview is not working properly in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I uploaded a some image file to the upload folder and set the featured image of the post. But when I login as administrator and edit the featured image, the media window shown an icon only, no preview showed[image]

Comment: I changed to basic theme, deactivated all the plugins. FIle permission changed to 644. but no changes occured

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the answer.

```
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file_path, '' );
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file_path );
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
$imageid = set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );
add_post_meta($post_id , '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the WordPress file permissions